# What is the term for "participant(s) registering by their own and not sent by a company"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

I'm thinking of "standalone participant" but that feels weird. "Participator" also word that comes to my mind, but I feel it's uncommon to be heard, and also does not have distinguishing marks from participants that are sent by company. Btw, while we're at it, is there also probably a better term for participants that *do* register under a company? Thanks.

Comment: Participants of _what_?

Comment: @TypeIA Participants of some kind of training or workshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most common usage would be "independant".

See also "independant contractor"

For the opposite, you may want to use: "sponsored applicant" or "sponsored participant".

Comment: Did you mean to type **independent**?

Comment: Interesting. I think I can use this. Thanks!!